# SQL query for finding first missing sequence string (prefix+no)

Tags: sql, sql-server

T-SQL query for finding first missing sequence string (prefix+no)

Sequence can have a prefix + a continuing no.

ex sequence will be

```
ID
-------
AUTO_500
AUTO_501
AUTO_502
AUTO_504
AUTO_505
AUTO_506
AUTO_507
AUTO_508
```

So above the missing sequence is AUTO_503 or if there is no missing sequence then it must return next sequence.

Also starting no is to specified ex. 500 in this case and prefix can be null i.e. no prefix only numbers as sequence.

Comment: If possible, [normalize your database](http://phlonx.com/resources/nf3/)

Comment: that is a good go but for now DB is freezed cant do that .. just need to extract solution out o this only......

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could `LEFT JOIN` the id numbers on shifted(+1) values to find gaps in sequential order:

```
SELECT 
    MIN(a.offsetnum) AS first_missing_num
FROM 
(
    SELECT 500 AS offsetnum
    UNION
    SELECT CAST(REPLACE(id, 'AUTO_', '') AS INT) + 1
    FROM tbl
) a
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT CAST(REPLACE(id, 'AUTO_', '') AS INT) AS idnum FROM tbl) b ON a.offsetnum = b.idnum
WHERE 
    a.offsetnum >= 500 AND b.idnum IS NULL
```

---

[SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/77df3/3/3)

Comment: 'Also starting no is to specified ex. 500' ... with ur solution if ID was supposed to start from AUTO_500 , but the ID entry starts from 501 it only shows the next missing no ie 503 not 500 thats why we need to specify starting range. plz update ur solution keeping this constraint as well .... thanks

Answer (score 3):

Using a recursive CTE to dynamically generate the sequence between the min and max of the ID Numbers maybe over complicated things a bit but it seems to work -

[LIVE ON FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/348b7/26)

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (
  id VARCHAR(55)
);

INSERT INTO tbl VALUES 
('AUTO_500'),
('AUTO_501'),
('AUTO_502'),
('AUTO_504'),
('AUTO_505'),
('AUTO_506'),
('AUTO_507'),
('AUTO_508'),
('509');

;WITH 

  data_cte(id)AS
    (SELECT [id] = CAST(REPLACE(id, 'AUTO_', '') AS INT) FROM tbl)

  ,maxmin_cte(minId, maxId)AS
    (SELECT [minId] = min(id),[maxId] = max(id) FROM data_cte) 

  ,recursive_cte(n) AS 
  (
     SELECT [minId] n from maxmin_cte
     UNION ALL
     SELECT (1 + n) n FROM recursive_cte WHERE n < (SELECT [maxId] from maxmin_cte)
  )

SELECT x.n 
FROM 
     recursive_cte x
     LEFT OUTER JOIN data_cte y ON
        x.n = y.id
WHERE y.id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this solution.Here you just need to add identity column.

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (
      id VARCHAR(55),
      idn int identity(0,1)
    );

    INSERT INTO tbl VALUES
    ('AUTO_500'),
    ('AUTO_501'),
    ('AUTO_502'),
    ('AUTO_504'),
    ('AUTO_505'),
    ('AUTO_506'),
    ('AUTO_507'),
    ('AUTO_508'),
    ('509');

    SELECT min(idn+500) FROM tbl  where 'AUTO_'+cast((idn+500) as varchar)<>id
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
with cte as(
select cast(REPLACE(id,'AUTO_','') as int)-500+1 [diff],ROW_NUMBER() 
over(order by cast(REPLACE(id,'AUTO_','') as int)) [rnk] from tbl)
select top 1 'AUTO_'+cast(500+rnk as varchar(50)) [ID] from cte 
where [diff]=[rnk] 
order by rnk desc
```

[SQL FIddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3456a/1)

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar situation, where we have R_Cds that were like this R01005

```
;with Active_R_CD (R_CD)
As
(
Select Distinct Cast(Replace(R_CD,'R', ' ') as Int) 
from table
where stat = 1)

select Arc.R_CD + 1 as 'Gaps in R Code'
from Active_R_CD as Arc
  left outer join Active_R_CD as r on ARC.R_CD + 1 = R.R_CD
where R.R_CD is null
order by 1
```